# How to convert Observable<any> to array[]

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have following method in typescript, I need to bind to angular grid

**CountryService**

```
GetCountries()  {
  return this.http.get(`http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all`)
    .map((res:Response) => <CountryData[]>res.json().RestResponse["result"]);
}
```

**GridComponent**

```
  template: `
        <ag-grid-ng2 style="width: 100%" #agGrid class="ag-material"
                    rowHeight="50"
                    [gridOptions]="myGridOptions" 
                     >
            </ag-grid-ng2>
        `,

  this.myGridOptions.rowData= this.CountryService.GetCountries();
```

**CountryData**

```
export class CountryData{
  name: string;
  alpha2_code: string;
  alpha3_code: string;
}
```

But GetCoutries will return Observable of any, unable to bind to rowData?

How to convert Observable to CountryData[] in typescript ?

you find JSON data here: http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all

Comment: You need to subscribe to the Observable: `this.CountryService.GetCountries().subscribe(result => this.myGridOptions.rowData = result);`

Comment: Can you check this json services.groupkt.com/country/get/all how to convert my CountryData[]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to your observables:

```
this.CountryService.GetCountries()
    .subscribe(countries => {
        this.myGridOptions.rowData = countries as CountryData[]
    })
```

And, in your html, wherever needed, you can pass the `async` pipe to it.

Comment: this.myGridOptions.rowData undefined . not binding data to grid

Comment: Can you check this json http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all  how to convert my CountryData[]

Comment: @Ragavan did you initialize your `this.myGridOptions.rowData` in your constructor?

Comment: Yes i'm initialized in constructor

Comment: @Ragavan You need to find out why your `this.myGridOptions.rowData` is undefined man. Use console to do the debugging

Comment: any issue with josn data ? If you have sample for your answer please give me a link . i will refer

Answer (score 27):

Using HttpClient (Http's replacement) in Angular 4.3+, the entire mapping/casting process is made simpler/eliminated.

Using your CountryData class, you would define a service method like this:

```
getCountries()  {
  return this.httpClient.get<CountryData[]>('http://theUrl.com/all');
}
```

Then when you need it, define an array like this:

```
countries:CountryData[] = [];
```

and subscribe to it like this:

```
this.countryService.getCountries().subscribe(countries => this.countries = countries);
```

A complete setup answer [is posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46838155/3075533) also.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
GetCountries():Observable<CountryData[]>  {
  return this.http.get(`http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all`)
    .map((res:Response) => <CountryData[]>res.json());
}
```

For this to work you will need to import the following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

Comment: i'm getting below error 
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Type 'Observable<CountryData>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<CountryData[]>'.
  Type 'CountryData' is not assignable to type 'CountryData[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'CountryData'.'
at: '90,3'
source: 'ts'

Answer (score 1):

**//Component.  home.ts  :**

```
  contacts:IContacts[];


ionViewDidLoad() {
this.rest.getContacts()
.subscribe( res=> this.contacts= res as IContacts[]) ;
```

**// reorderArray. accepts only Arrays**

```
    Reorder(indexes){
  reorderArray(this.contacts, indexes)
}
```

**// Service .  res.ts**

```
getContacts(): Observable<IContacts[]> {
return this.http.get<IContacts[]>(this.apiUrl+"?results=5")
```

**And it works fine**

Answer (score 1):

You can convert any observable to an array using lastValueFrom and toArray:

```
import * as rxjs from 'rxjs'
import * as rxops from 'rxjs/operators'

console.log(await rxjs.lastValueFrom(rxjs.from([1,2,3]).pipe(rxops.toArray())))
```

prints

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

toArray "collects all source emissions and emits them as an array when the source completes."  lastValueFrom just converts the last (well, the only, since toArray scoops up everything) value of the array to a promise.

Comment: I'm curious about the wildcard imports. Will those be optimized by the compiler to remove unused items?