# How can I instantiate an array of objects from an Observable<Object[]> in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, observable

I have this in my .ts file

```
myobj: Observable<MyObj[]>;
```

which I can loop through in my `HTML` file to see all `myObj[]` coming from my API

is it possible to turn this `Observable` into an `Array` of `MyObj`?

Comment: Yes: subscribe to the observable. https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Comment: `Array<MyObj> === MyObj[] ` , so you already have that, Observable is just for the async stream of data.You need to subscribe on that

Comment: see this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44940857/2126355)

Comment: Thanks everyone, that link helped me to solve my problem. After subscribing correctly I was able to get the array I wanted on my component!

Answer (score -1):

You can use [*ngFor directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) with [asyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) in your HTML template.

Your case:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of myobj | async">
  {{obj}}
</ng-container>
```