# Cannot get synchronization from inside subscribe to outside subscribe using localStorage or sessionStorage

Tags: angular, angular6

I have this mapping:

```
User     *----------------------------1     Role
```

From the list of users, I go to consult one user from this list.
To get some informations about that selected user, I need to use `localSorage` to get an object from **inside subscribe** to **outside subscribe**.

Bellow is the method:

```
this.userService.getAllRolesOfActualUser(user.id).subscribe(listRoles =>
{

     let roles:Array<Role> = [];

     if (listRoles)
     {
         listRoles.forEach((role) =>
         {
             roles.push(new Role(role.id, role.name, role.selected));
         });
     }

     sessionStorage.removeItem("roles");
     sessionStorage.setItem("roles", JSON.stringify(roles));
     console.log("1. Inside Subscribe- " + user.id + "--------------: " + 
     sessionStorage.getItem("roles"));

});

console.log("2. Outside Subscribe- " + user.id + "--------------: " + sessionStorage.getItem("roles"));
```

On **user.service.ts**, I have:

```
getAllRolesOfActualUser(id: number): Observable<any>
    {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/roles/${id}`);
    }
```

My problem is that usually I got the value of the previous consulted user not the actual user a described by this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GcGS.png):

Could you please help me solving that issue ?!.
Big thanks.

Comment: to explain in simple terms, code inside `subscribe` is executed asynchronously. which means when the execution reaches second `console.log` statement, the code inside `subscribe` has not been executed yet. the reason is that it gets executed whenever your http call completes and program doesn't know when it will happen, that's why it is executed asynchronously. put your second `console.log` into subscribe block and you will get correct results. but i think you are trying to use `roles` synchronously somewhere else and this will not remedy your actual problem. so what r u actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Sir @ysf for your reply. But I need that object outside subscribe, that what actually trying to do.

Comment: I need `roles` to fill checklist and that will done outside subscribe.

Comment: please share the code for filling the checklist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use **promise**:

```
    ses : String[];
    expertises : String[] = [];

    async getUri(userId: number)
        {
            let affected = this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUserPromise(userId);

            await affected.then((uri) =>
            {
                this.ses = uri;
            })

            return this.ses;
        }
```

and on ngOnInit, I have

```
this.getUri(16).then(item => 
        {
            item.forEach(pro=>
            {
                this.expertises.push(pro);
            });
        });
```

on the service file, you have:

```
getExpertisesListByIdUserPromise(id: number): Promise<any>
    {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/expertises/${id}`).toPromise();
    }
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you actually want to achieve, but if you want to the result "outside the subscribe" directly below in your example, you will probably have to run your code in a more synchronous way.

For example you could use a Promise instead of an Observable and await the execution:

```
await this.userService.getAllRolesOfActualUser(user.id).then(listRoles =>
{

 let roles:Array<Role> = [];

 if (listRoles)
 {
     listRoles.forEach((role) =>
     {
         roles.push(new Role(role.id, role.name, role.selected));
     });
 }

 sessionStorage.removeItem("roles");
 sessionStorage.setItem("roles", JSON.stringify(roles));
 console.log("1. Inside Subscribe- " + user.id + "--------------: " + 
 sessionStorage.getItem("roles"));

});

console.log("2. Outside Subscribe- " + user.id + "--------------: " + sessionStorage.getItem("roles"));
```

And in your service:

```
getAllRolesOfActualUser(id: number): Promise<any>
{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/roles/${id}`).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: Hello Sir @LeBavarois, Thanks a lot for your reply. But I got this error `'await' expression is only allowed within an async function`.

Comment: You need to add the keyword `async` to the function within which you use `await`.

Comment: I got `Cannot find name 'async'` when I tried with `async await this.userService.getAllRolesOfActualUser(user.id).then(listRoles =>`

Comment: Okay, maybe my comment was bit unclear. The function that is using await in its body has to have the async keyword.Assuming you want to get the roles when a users is selected, your code could look like this:
`async onUserSelected(User user) {
  await this.userService.getAllRolesOfActualUser(user.id); // an so on
}`

Answer (score 1):

[source](https://dev.to/ccleary00/how-to-rewrite-a-callback-function-in-promise-form-and-asyncawait-form-in-javascript-410e)
**So you have to work with Promise:**

```
      getData(){
            var promiseData =return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              this.userService.getAllRolesOfActualUser(user.id).subscribe('........')
                    .subscribe(
                     data => {

    //your handlings
                      resolve(data)
                    },
                     error => {
                      reject(error);
                    },
            );
                });
return promiseData;
        }
```

**And in your controller:**

```
getData().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
//do here what you want
    })
```

if you figer it out simply test this and check

```
doAsyncTask() {
  let error = true;
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if (error) {
         reject('error'); // pass values
       } else {
         resolve('done'); // pass values
       }
     }, 1000);
   });
 }

 this.doAsyncTask().then(
  (val) => console.log(val),
  (err) => console.error(err)
);
```

********* My Edit according to your proposition

```
doAsyncTask() {
  let error = true;
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if (error) {
         reject('error'); // pass values
       } else {
         this.userService.getExpertisesListByIdUserObj(2)
                // .subscribe('........')
                .subscribe(listExpertises =>
                      {
                        console.log("YES");
                          let exps:Array<Expertise> = [];

                          if (listExpertises)
                          {
                              listExpertises.forEach((expert) =>
                              {
                                  exps.push(new Expertise(expert.id, expert.name, expert.selected));
                              });
                          }

                          sessionStorage.removeItem("exps");
                          sessionStorage.setItem("exps", JSON.stringify(exps));
                          console.log("1. MODIF-IN " + 2 + "--------------: " + sessionStorage.getItem("exps"));

              });
         resolve('done'); // pass values
       }
     }, 1000);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks a lot for your reply. But, I got `Property 'then' doesn't not exist on type Subscription`

Comment: Hello Sir @ORBIT, thanks a lot for your reply. I made the method `getData()` on my controller. and I called it on **ngOnInit()**,  `this.getData().then(data => {
      console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++" + data);
    })` but I got any thing, the console isn't shown

Comment: UPDATED CODE CHECK

Comment: Hu Sir, I did that, but the console produces: `Object { __zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: [] } ` and  `[object Promise] ` on **ngOnInit()**

Comment: Hello Sir, I got anything on console when I call `this.doAsyncTask().then(
  (value) => console.log(value),
  (error) => console.error(error)
);` on **ngOnInit()**. However I got correct result on the function.

Comment: Good if it helped

Comment: Thanks Sir, But I don't get anything on **ngOnInit()**, Have you please any idea on how can I resolve this problem ?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your `user.service.ts` you are getting just one object from your pool of objects `(Array of Objects)` and in your component.ts You are saving your payload as a stringified object so to get the desired result you need to convert it back to JSON by doing

```
let role = sessionStorage.getItem('roles');
let rolesObject = JSON.parse('role')

console.log("1. LIST- " + user.id + "--------------: " +  rolesObject;
```

I don't know why you are doing the array.push but i think you should just go with the payload in your `listRoles`.